# BOTO ResourceRecordSets object convert to string

Tags: python, string, object, boto

How to convert an ResourceRecordSets  to string ? I need to get like the blabla.lt, A, and 1.1.1.1 separately in strings.
It is on BOTO Route53.
Running on Ubuntu, Python 2.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Boto documentation doesn't give a lot of detail about the structure of the Route53 classes. You can easily work it out however by using `dir()` on returned objects, for example `dir(conn.get_zone("your zone."))`

Eventually, you'll find that you can access all the attributes of each `record` object, including `type`, `name` and `resource_records` (In your case, the IP address).

You should end up with something like:

```
conn = boto.route53.connection.Route53Connection(aws_access_key_id = aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key = aws_secret_access_key)

zone = conn.get_zone("your.zone.")

for record in zone.get_records():
  print "Type: %s, name: %s, values: %s" % (record.type, record.name, ",".join(record.resource_records))
```